# Images in UICollectionView cells overlapping

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am using a horizontal UICollectionView. Each cell of it has assigned an image, the problem is that when I scroll the collectionView, the images are overlapping so they get new placed over the old right image of another cell, below you can see what I mean. Can someone tell what the problem is? Thanks in advance!

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "category", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
    cell.setUpView(txt: categories[indexPath.row], image: symbols[indexPath.row]!)
    return cell
}
```

Here is my setUp() function for the CategoryCell:

```
func setUpView(txt: String, image: UIImage) {
    view.backgroundColor = CustomColor.soft_pink
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
    view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 168).isActive = true
    
    //Label
    view.addSubview(label)
    label.text = txt
    label.font = UIFont(name: "DamascusBold", size: 15)
    label.textColor = .white
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 130).isActive = true
    label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    
    let symbolView = UIImageView(image: image)
    
    view.addSubview(symbolView)
    symbolView.tintColor = .white
    symbolView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    symbolView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    symbolView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    symbolView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    symbolView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
    symbolView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
}
```

[Images in Cells overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkpCs.png)

Comment: Can you share your setUpView method?

Comment: @ArnabAhamedSiam I did

Comment: Very simple! At the start of your `setUpView`, before any other code, say this: `view.removeConstraints(view.constraints); view.subviews.forEach {$0.removeFromSuperview()}` Do you see why?

Comment: Voting to reopen on the grounds that the question is now readily answerable.

Comment: Cells are reused. That's the concept your are missing. You are calling `view.addSubview(symbolView)` each time, so that's where is your issue. You shouldn't call all the same code each time (beside the reuse issue, you set each time again and again the constraints and other settings). `setUpView(txt:image:)` should be call on `awakeFromNib` or `init` method, and in `cellForRowAt`, you should call `update(withText: String, image: UIImage) { symbolView.image = image; label.text = text }`

Comment: @matt Great thank you!